# Decode maximum number in rows for sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, google-bigquery

I am using the `#standardsql` in bigquery and trying to code the maksimum ranking of each customer_id as `1`, and the rest of it are `0`

This is the query result so far

[image: rankings customer_id]

The query for ranking is this

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY booking_date Asc) as ranking
```

What i need is to create another column like this where it decode the maximum ranking of each `customerid` as 1, and the number below it as `0` just like the below table

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, your ranking is *unstable*, because you have multiple rows with the same key values.  In any case, you can still do what you want without subqueries, just using `case`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by booking_date asc) as ranking,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by booking_date asc) =
                  count(*) over (partition by customer_id)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as custom_coded
from t;
```

A more traditional way of doing essentially the same thing would be to use a descending sort:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by booking_date asc) as ranking,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by booking_date desc) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as custom_coded
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap your current query, and then use `MAX` as an analytic function with a partition by customer to compare each `ranking` value against the max `ranking` for each customer.  When the `ranking` value equals the maximum value for a customer, then we assign 1 for the `custom_coded`, otherwise we assign 0.

```
SELECT
    customer_id, item_bought, booking_date, ranking,
    CASE WHEN ranking = MAX(ranking) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS custom_coded
FROM
(
    SELECT customer_id, item_bought, booking_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY booking_date) ranking
    FROM yourTable
) t;
```