# Row number custom coded in sql

Tags: sql, window-functions, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery `#standardsql` to work on a table. The table will note a conversion (1) for user who purchase something in month 9 and month 10. And for user who did not purchase at month 10, will only have `0` in their row

So far , this is the query for `custom_coded`

```
(case when row_number() 
  over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date asc) =
                  count(*) over (partition by customer_id)
             then 1 else 0 END) AS custom_coded
```

and this is the result so far
[image: result]

What i expect is that `customer_id = 288` only have `0` in `custom_coded` since he did not purchase in next month, or month 10. And `customer_id = 879` expected to have `1` in his latest `purchase_date` since he have a purchase record at month 10

This is the expected result 
[image: expected result]

I previously asked in this thread ([Decode maximum number in rows for sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530329/decode-maximum-number-in-rows-for-sql/47530622#47530622)), however the dataset didn't satisfy the idea for the analysis that i'm going to executed

Comment: Do you want September or October in any year, or just 2017?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen , it's only 2017. So the customer have to purchase 2 consecutive month in order to get `1` notation in their `custom_coded` column.
I actually try and got this one

```(case when row_number() 
  over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date asc) =
                  count(*) over (partition by customer_id)
                  AND purchase_date < '2017-10-01'
             then 1 else 0 END) AS custom_coded```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but that query wasn't correct. since if the user only purchase at month 9 for 1 time, he naturally coded as `1`. Where it should be `0`

Comment: Until now, your specifications are unclear and contradicting. You state value 1 should be given to 1)"user who purchase something in month 9 and month 10" 2) "purchase in next month, or month 10" 3) negate "only purchase at month 9 for 1 time". So clarify: Should it be 1 on the last customer line if he has purchased in months 9 AND 10? 9 OR 10? N AND N+1? N OR N+1?

Comment: ok, I guess after the first case condition you need something like AND exists( select 1 from table where month(purchase_date)=1+ <month you've put in where clause>). I'm not familiar enough with bigquery to know how this can be done though.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis This dataset shows all customer purchase in month 9. In order to be `1`, the user should purchase in month 9 and month 10 . Else should be `0` . 
Hope it's clear for the spec

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis thx , i added exists function on the first case as your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT customer_id, item_purchased, purchase_date, 
  (CASE WHEN 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY purchase_date ASC) =
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id)
    AND SUM(DISTINCT (CASE FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', purchase_date) 
        WHEN '201709' THEN 1 WHEN '201710' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) = 3
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
  END) AS custom_coded
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 288 customer_id, 'Rice' item_purchased, DATE '2017-09-02' purchase_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 288, 'Rice', DATE '2017-09-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 288, 'Rice', DATE '2017-09-06' UNION ALL
  SELECT 879, 'Plate', DATE '2017-09-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 879, 'Plate', DATE '2017-09-25' UNION ALL
  SELECT 879, 'Plate', DATE '2017-10-25' UNION ALL
  SELECT 879, 'Plate', DATE '2017-10-27' 
)
SELECT customer_id, item_purchased, purchase_date, 
  (CASE WHEN 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY purchase_date ASC) =
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id)
    AND SUM(DISTINCT (CASE FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', purchase_date) 
        WHEN '201709' THEN 1 WHEN '201710' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) = 3
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
  END) AS custom_coded
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY customer_id, purchase_date
```

result is

```sql
customer_id item_purchased  purchase_date   custom_coded     
288         Rice            2017-09-02      0    
288         Rice            2017-09-02      0    
288         Rice            2017-09-06      0    
879         Plate           2017-09-01      0    
879         Plate           2017-09-25      0    
879         Plate           2017-10-25      0    
879         Plate           2017-10-27      1
```

Comment: I missed the AND in the first case when function, thx for pointing it out and the dummy data helps!